# Mixture model for decomposing bimodal or multimodal distributions

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

The gaussian mixture model (GMM) is fed mixture components or features whose time series each have differing means and variances from one another, but are **unimodal** (have one mode) with each component forming a differently placed Gaussian distribution.

Can this instead be done recursively (backwards) somehow, where if, starting with **bimodal**-distributed mixture components that each have bimodal distributions (two modes, as shown in the image), is there a model that can **back out unimodal data series** or parameters from bimodal components? So instead of classifying sub-populations, you actually split apart the bimodal into sub-populations

[image]

Comment: This is the only application I can think of where the distributions are so well known that the data can be split back: https://bitesizebio.com/28687/carrying-gas-chromatography/

Comment: Flow cytometry is another example